# Session interchanged in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a multiple login system in codeigniter. I logged in to different accounts at the same time in different systems.When I refresh the page the logged in account changes to last logged account.That is if i logged as user1 and user2 respectively ,after refresh user1 changes as user2.

I have tried,

```
$config['sess_save_path']               = 'ci_sessions';
```

My session details are,

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']             = 'cmt_session';
$config['sess_expiration']              = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close']         = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']          = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']            = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']              = 'cmt_session';
$config['sess_match_ip']                = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']         = FALSE;
$config['sess_save_path']               = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_time_to_update']          = 300;
```

Comment: please describe "in different systems": same PC, different browsers? OR same PC, same browser, 2 different windows? OR 2 different devices (PC and tablet)?